# Why do automakers use "Blue" to refer to eco features?

Tags: vw, mercedes-benz

This one has me puzzled. Automakers seem to use "Blue" to refer to eco stuff when it comes to our cars. For example, my VW Golf R (not exactly an eco-wagon) has a "Blue Trainer" which teaches you how to drive economically, they use "Think Blue™" in their marketing, and have BlueMotion badged cars that are more fuel efficient and emit fewer nasties. Similarly, Mercedes use BlueTEC on their diesels for the same purpose. I guess Blue would make sense with hybrid/electric vehicles, but mine is definitely not that!

Why "Blue"? Why not "Green" or "Eco"? Is there some strict definition for Green or Eco? A trademark?

Comment: And addblue ...

Comment: Because it Sells!

Answer (score 2):

Of course many do not use "Blue" - Skoda use "Green", for example. Others just use the word "Eco."

But why is "Blue" so common? This actually comes from Volkswagen's corporate colour initially. They were first to market with a commercially successful product that reduced NO emissions. Other car manufacturers have taken the branding effect and run with it, as an existing brand effect helps with marketing.